# Yii2,I want to change my url like "aaaa.bbbb.cccc.dddd/app/web" to any name like "example.com" .How can I achieve this

Tags: yii2

I'm implementing my site from godaddy to ASW server.

I want to change my url like `aaaa.bbbb.cccc.dddd/app/web` to any name like `example.com`.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: You have to point your domain to this folder. You can find info about this in the [Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html#configuring-web-servers)

Comment: Hi , You can achieve this by adding your ec2 DNS server to godaddy CNAME.